# Equivalence of modes of convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

The problem in hand is:

> If $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space, $(E, d_{E})$ be a metric space and $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb N_{0}$, $X_{n} : \Omega \to E$ be $\mathcal F/(E, d_{E})$-strongly measurable mappings. Then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> i) $\forall$ $c \in (0, \infty)$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb E[\min\{c,d_{E}(X_{0},X_{n})\}] = 0$
>
> ii) $\exists$ $c \in (0, \infty)$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb E[\min\{c,d_{E}(X_{0},X_{n})\}] = 0$
>
> iii) $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P(d_{E}(X_{0},X_{n}) \gt \epsilon) = 0$

Now, obviously i) $\implies$ ii) is trivial.

For, ii) $\implies$ iii) , what I am thinking is: since ii) is true for some $c \gt 0$, that $c$ has to be greater than $d_{E}(X_{0},X_{n})$,  $\forall n \in \mathbb N_{0}$, otherwise the assumption can't hold true. So the assumption boils down to $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb E [d_{E}(X_{0},X_{n})] = 0$. And then we can obtain iii) by means of Markov's Inequality.

But for iii) $\implies $ i), I am stuck. No clues about what to do. So, any help or solution is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. :- Also, is my solution about ii) $\implies$ iii) correct ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could help you for iii) $\Longrightarrow$ i):

Take any $c>0$ and let $0<\epsilon < c$. We now split the expectation as follows:

$\begin{align*}
E[\min\{c,d_E(X_0,X_n)\}] &= E[\min\{c,d_E(X_0,X_n)\}\mathbb{1}_{\{d_E(X_0,X_n) ≤ \epsilon\}}] + E[\min\{c,d_E(X_0,X_n)\}\mathbb{1}_{\{d_E(X_0,X_n) > \epsilon\}}]
\end{align*} ≤ \epsilon + cE[\mathbb{1}_{\{d_E(X_0,X_n) > \epsilon\}}] = \epsilon + cP[d_E(X_0,X_n) > \epsilon]
$

Now take the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ to obtain

$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E[\min\{c,d_E(X_0,X_n)\}] ≤ \epsilon
\end{align*}
$

using iii). You can conclude by letting $\epsilon$ go to $0$ as the above holds for any $\epsilon$ smaller than $c$ and greater than $0$.